# Mysql How to select all orders and the items within the orders

Tags: php, mysql, sql

OK I have 3 tables one with products in it, One with the orders in it and join table with the order ids and product ids to associate products with orders.

But how do I set up a query that will select and return all orders as well as the items within each order. So I end up with a column order_items in each row.

So far I have:

```
SELECT
  intOrderID AS Order_ID, 
  strPaymentMethod AS Payment_Method,
  strPaymentRef, AS Payment_Ref, 
  strPaymentStatus AS Payment_Status,
  dtmDate AS Date, 
  curPaymentAmount AS Net_Price, 
  curShippingFee AS Shipping_Fee 
FROM tbl_mod_ShopOrders
```

The other table is `tbl_mod_ShopOrderItems` and I need to select

```
intProductID
strProductTitle
curPrice
intQty
```

for each item within the order.

I know I need to do some sort of subquery but note sure how to construct it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are `PRODUCT`, `ORDER` and the joining table `PRODUCTORDER` has keys `product_id` and `order_id`, you can:

```
SELECT o.id, GROUP_CONCAT(po.product_id) AS products_list
FROM PRODUCT p, PRODUCTORDER po
WHERE o.id = po.order_id
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY o.id
```

As aggregate function use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function%5Fgroup-concat). The above results in, for instance:

```
id | products_list
---|--------------
01 | 1,4,9
02 | 2,4,6
03 | 5
04 | 3,5
```

where `id` is the ORDER id.

Comment: I don't actually need to select anything from the products table as joining table has the product title and product id in it. but that looks along the right lines

Answer (score 0):

Each order would have several items. That means that when you select the orders, each row could have one or more items.

If you need to simply display something simple like the number of items in each order, you can retrieve all that information easily with one query.

But, if you need to display detailed information regarding the items in each order (e.g. item, quantity, price), it would be easier perform a second query, retrieving the item information.
This second query can be executed for each order or only once for all orders displayed (create an array with the displayed order ids and select all items belonging to those ids using the `IN` clause).

Example for detailed scenario:

```
//$orders = array of orders retrieved by your query

// loop through the orders to collect all ids
$order_ids = array();
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $order_ids[] = $order->Order_ID;
}

// build the select to retrieve all items
$items = array();

// make the select only if there are orders available
if(count($order_ids) > 0) {
      $q = "SELECT * from tbl_mod_ShopOrderItems WHERE order_id IN (" . implode(',', $order_ids) . ") ";
       // ...
       // assign result to $items
}
```

Later, when displaying the orders, you can loop through the `$items` and check if the `order_id` matches your current `order`

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    // ...
    // display order info

    // display order items
    foreach($items as $item) {
         // if the item belongs to the current order
         if($item->order_id == $order->order_id) {
             // ...
             // display the current item
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one of the cases described above fits better to your problem? I don't know for what case you need the example.

Comment: The detailed information regarding the items in each order case